# Can I update to a newer version of libreoffice in 16.04?

Tags: apt, libreoffice

I would like to update to a newer libreoffice version than the presently installed.

Presently I have:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade libreoffice
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libreoffice is already the newest version (1:6.2.8~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-198 linux-headers-4.4.0-198-generic linux-image-4.4.0-198-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-198-generic linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-198-generic linux-tools-4.4.0-198 linux-tools-4.4.0-198-generic python3-google-compute-engine
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04 and I would like to install libreoffice 6.3 or newer.

This information might be relevant, too:

```
grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d|grep -i libreoffice
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-libreoffice-6-4-xenial.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-6-4/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-libreoffice-6-4-xenial.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-6-4/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-libreoffice-6-4-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-6-4/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-libreoffice-6-4-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-6-4/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ppa-trusty.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu xenial main # disabled on upgrade to xenial
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ppa-trusty.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ppa-trusty.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu xenial main # disabled on upgrade to xenial
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ppa-trusty.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ppa-trusty.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ppa-trusty.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-libreoffice-6-3-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-6-3/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-libreoffice-6-3-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-6-3/ubuntu xenial main
```

Comment: Is remaining on Ubuntu 16.04 a requirement? It loses Community Support quite soon, in April 2021. Newer releases of Ubuntu have newer software. Ubuntu 20.04, for example, has LibreOffice 6.4.

Comment: [6.2.8](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=xenial) is the max for 16.04 LTS. You have to upgrade to 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about PPA / apt but you could try the .deb from libreoffice website after removing the one you installed with apt.

But since support for 16.04 ends in three month it would possibly be best to upgrade your Ubuntu installation anyways.